# WIndows XP desktop, CD drive and no USB boot option

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu, windows-xp

I have a Dell 2400 Inspiron system with a CD drive. Lately its become sluggish in operation and I decided to load Kubuntu on it. But I have run into a roadblock. 
My machine doesn't have the USB flash boot option (checked the bios option and not possible) and I am not able to burn a CD with the ISO image as its size is smaller than what the boot image requires. 
How do I get Kubuntu on my desktop ?Is there any other way ?
thanks.

Comment: You might want to try a [Netboot Image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/).  The amd64 version of 13.10 is only 36MB but has no GUI installer and sometimes requires manual network config.  This has just enough to boot your system but requires every package to be downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way and i've used it before, You will need a cd, but the size doesn't matter. There are many other ways. You can use Plop: http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html to install it you burn the iso. Then boot of it, and select usb to boot of your usb with ubuntu on it.